# Blazor webassembly pwa session storage not persisting after deployment to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, local-storage, blazor, blazor-client-side

I am developing a Blazor webassembly pwa, locally running the project will store the user in the session storage and keep them there.

But when I deploy to Azure (linux app service) the session/local storage is not persisting. So when navigating to a different page (within my application) or refreshing the page the oidc.user variable is removed from the session storage and therefor my user is logged out.

[image: local working session storage]

- Locally it's working and the key pair will persist.

[image]

- When deployed to Azure the same key will be added after loggin in succesfully but after a redirect it's removed.

So the real question is: **Why is my session storage working locally but does it remove the oidc.user key pair after a redirect, Causing the user to be logged out.**

Comment: You said that when you are running your app locally, the token is stored in the local storage. Your screenshot shows the session store. The [session store](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) is cleared on refresh. What do you mean by "different page"?. A different ```@page``` but within the same blazor application?  Is there a reason for not using local storage to persist the token?

Comment: @Justthebenno Yes a different   '@page' within the same application. The token is put in the local storage when logged in, but it is removed when navigating to a different '@page' or refreshing the browser window. The token being removed is my issue, and i do not know why this happens.

Comment: I don't see a value whose Key is something like this:  "oidc.user:https://localhost:44308:BlazorApp1.Client"

Comment: @enet Exactly, that is my problem. It does get stored for about half a second something like oidc.user etc en then after a redirect or navigating to another page within my application its no longer there. Because of that my user now is logged out. This problem only is here after deploying, running it locally works.

Comment: @MeesvanStraten Have you found a solution?  I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @TylerBrinks Sadly I did not, it was a pet project so I probably quit trying after a while, don't remember exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Exactly, that is my problem. It does get stored for about half a second something like oidc.user etc en then after a redirect or navigating to another page within my application its no longer there. Because of that my user now is logged out. This problem only is here after deploying, running it locally works.

It seems as though the session cookie is being deleted immediately after a request is made. Note: The cookie session ID is sent to the server at each request.

This may be only a guesswork, but you better try it than not...

Add the following code to your CongiureServices:

```
   services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });
```

And `app.UseSession();` in the Configure method, immediately above `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>`

Hope this works...

Note: AuthenticationStateProvider has got nothing to do with the issue you're facing.

Comment: Sadly does not work, However I have an Blazor webassembly so it does not have a startup.cs , But adding it in the program.cs does not make any difference.

When adding test key value with Blazored that does work, And it persists. So it looks like something is going on with the default Blazor auth provider, thats responsible for creating a item in the storage right? Thats why I mentioned it if it was possible to override that part of the auth provider.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps because I've been experiencing the same:

1. My blazor app and the IDP are *not* on the same domain;
2. Third-party cookies are disabled;
3. IDP is identityserve4/duende;

For some reason, **right after the login**, the AuthenticationService library tries to "check_session" using iframe which fails due to #1 and #2. Due to the failure, it deletes the "oidc.user:{client_id}" record from the session storage and the subsequent requests to your backend.

### Solution

The author [here](https://infi.nl/nieuws/spa-necromancy/) speaks well about the problem and possible solutions.

### Workaround

You can patch the AuthenticationService.js file, creating your own and removing the session check, or changing the frequency of it. At least, it will give your application back the access token lifetime.

These 2 keys are good candidates to be modified.

```
{
   key: "monitorSession",
      get: function () {
         return _monitorSession; //maybe return false? 
      },
}
```

```
{
   key: "checkSessionInterval",
      get: function () {
         return this._checkSessionInterval;
      },
   },
}
```